# Monitor a web page for when a desired price is met

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I have a code that keeps checking a webpage with a price on it and when the price meets a number I set it to, the thing is purchased. I am looking for ways to increase the speed of it.

I have added multiprocessing and its performance may have improved, but I don't know if its the best-case scenario for this code and there probably are better methods for speed and efficiency.

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from functools import partial

session = requests.session()
session.cookies["cookie"] = ""

login = session.get("https://www.example.com")
if login.status_code == 200:
    print("logged in")
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Cookie")

crsf_token = ""

def token():
    while True:
        global crsf_token
        crsf_token = re.search(r"<script>XsrfToken.setToken\('(.*?)'\);</script>", session.get('https://www.example.com').text).group(1)
        time.sleep(5)

def _cthread():
    with Pool() as pool:
        while True:
            try:
                req = session.get(f"https://www.example.com")
                if req.status_code == 429:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue

                allposts = [f'https://www.example.com&Price={i["Price"]}'
                        for i in req.json()["data"]["Sellers"] if i["Price"] <= 10]
                if allposts:
                    pool.map(partial(session.post, headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": crsf_token}), allposts)
            except requests.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError as E:
                pass


threading.Thread(target=_cthread).start()
threading.Thread(target=token).start()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Constant reuse

Store your base URL, `"https://www.example.com"`, in a constant for reuse.

### HTTP codes

Some status codes, such as 200, are common and obvious, while others such as 429 are less so. Fundamentally these are all magic numbers, and `requests.codes` contains symbols - including `too_many_requests`.

### URL construction

```
           allposts = [f'https://www.example.com&Price={i["Price"]}'
                    for i in req.json()["data"]["Sellers"] if i["Price"] <= 10]
```

Firstly - you don't need to be adding the URL in here. You can move the query parameter to the `params` dict to be passed to `session.post`. Then the URL can be passed to `session.post` directly without any baked-in query parameters.

### Variable case

```
ConnectTimeoutError as E:
```

Don't capitalize `E` since it's a variable. Past that, you shouldn't even write `as E`, since you aren't using the exception.

### Import long-form symbols

```
requests.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError
```

would benefit from an import of this class so that you can use it without package qualification.